# Change the order index of multiindex at levels=0 due to a list

Tags: pandas, sorting, multi-index

I have multiindex like this:

```
                                     col1           col2          col3  ...     
Chars        Date                                                       ...
A            2020 January             4.0        1,417.0       1,136.0  ...                            
             2020 February                         .
             2020 March                            .
             2020 April                            .
             2020 May
             2020 June
             2020 July
             2020 Agust
             2020 September
             2020 October
             2020 November
             2020 December
B            2020 January             4.0        1,007.0         975.0  ...
             2020 February                          .
             2020 March                             .
             2020 April                             .
             2020 May
             2020 June
             2020 July
             2020 Agust
             2020 September
             2020 October
             2020 November
             2020 December                     

.
.
.
```

I want to order this multiindex's index at levels=0.('Chars'). But I want to change the order of index due to a list. I have tried:

```
order_list = ['B', 'C', 'Z', 'Y' ... 'E', 'A']

df = df.loc[order_list]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `output = df.reindex(order_list,level=0)`  ?

Comment: I am embarrassed to ask this question, I am deleting it.

Comment: You shouldn't be , its perfectly natural to get stuck :-), also please don't delete the question. that defeats the purpose of SO.

Comment: I have been busy with different codes for about 10 hours today. I couldn't figure it out. Thank you!